# start_url problem The start_url did respond, but not via a service worker. it works on local perectly but not on server

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am a new with service worker. The start_url is defined in manifest.json. Everything works perfectly on localhost and PWA options are all green. But on the server, this message is shown "start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline start_url did respond, but not via a service worker."
The website is "https://www.zamanha.com/" and the service worker is "https://www.zamanha.com/manifest.json" and the service worker handler is "https://www.zamanha.com/main.js" and service worker "https://www.zamanha.com/sw.js" can anyone help me. I checked all solutions everywhere and it drives me crazy.

Comment: In fetch event of service worker Instead of matching request object can you change it to cache.match(event.request.url) and try.

Comment: thx. it works but when i change the page i got the error "Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error."

Comment: Where are you getting this error.? Can you please mentioned the step to reproduce that?

Comment: sorry. It was my bad. The probelem is it does not go on offlien after error on line 74 service worker

Comment: That's because your application is using jquery-3.5.1.min.js and in your sw cachelist you have specified version jquery-3.4.1.min.js. Please use  the same version in both the place and make sure to cache all the static files which is used by your application to make the app work in offline mode.

Comment: thx. it works fine. You are the most professional.

Comment: can you also have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354810/beforeinstallprompt-does-not-work-on-console-log

Answer (score 0):

as answered by  Vimal Patel it should just change (cache.match(evt.request) to cache.match(evt.request.url)

Answer (score 0):

Initially as you were matching  the request object directly with cache, for some reason(mostly due to request headers) it was returning `undefined` even if that file was in cache. Changing it to get the file based on url will fetch the resources correctly.

There was a jQuery version mismatch. Your application was using jquery-3.5.1.min.js and in your service worker cache list you have specified version jquery-3.4.1.min.js. Because of that application was not working in offline mode.

if your application needs to be working offline make sure to cache all the static files so that your application will work in offline mode as all the required files are served from cached.