# beforeinstallprompt does not work on console.log

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

on https://www.zamanha.com/sw.js on self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
the console.log() does not work. anyone?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in below. but it is very important to put it in the main.js that runs service worker like sw.js. after regissteration of service worker

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
} else {
    console.log('CLIENT: service worker is not supported.');
}
```

this code ----->

```
var deferredPrompt;
self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
      console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired');
      e.preventDefault();
      deferredPrompt = e.originalEvent;
      return false;
});
```